# get post id from long url (php)

Tags: php, mysql

hello i have post url like that

http://localhost/pa/news.php?post=2/test-title-test

news.php? = news template

2 in (post =2 ) = post id in mysql 
and test-title-test is article title

i want to get only post id to use it on mysql order and load content order by id

http://localhost/pa/news.php?post=**2**/test-title-test

when i trying to use  $id = $_GET['post'];
it echos 2/test-title-test
i need to echo only id **2**

are there any other ways to get post id from url tu use it for mysql order?
thanks

Comment: Which HTTP server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the post-param.

Pre PHP 5.5:

```
$postParts = explode('/', $_GET['post']);
$postId    = $postParts[0];
```

PHP 5.5+:

```
$postId = explode('/', $_GET['post'])[0];
```